# OpenMP using lock

Tags: openmp

Why the program did not speed up and become slower than the sequential version?
Will it be faster if I change the lock to omp reduction?

The omp code for the calculation avgvalue

[image]

Comment: Please do not use screenshots here, copy the sourcode as text. It is **very** important.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple threads running a single critical command. That is basically just as efficient as a serial code since only one thread will execute at a time. And you are also adding overhead by creating multiple threads and having them wait on one another to finish their execution before they can execute.

I think that making a reduction would be faster, since there are optimizations for that command in OpenMP.